# Scroll bar does not move when sorting options in MultiSelect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multi-select box which has 2 buttons on the right which are sorting an option up and down the list.  This works fine, however if I move the option up or below the top or bottom boundary of the multiselect the scrollbar won't take that into effect and move accordingly.  Any suggestions?

JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mup")[0].attachEvent("onclick", moveUpItem);
  $("#mdown")[0].attachEvent("onclick", moveDownItem);
});

function moveUpItem() {
  $('#list option:selected').each(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
  });
}

function moveDownItem() {
  $('#list option:selected').each(function() {
    $(this).insertAfter($(this).next());
  });
}

//Holding down the Up/Down buttons
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timer;
  $("#mup, #mdown").on('mousedown', function() {
    if (this.id === 'mup') {
      timer = setInterval(moveUpItem, 250);
    } else {
      timer = setInterval(moveDownItem, 250);
    }
  }).on('mouseup', function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#list").each(function() {
      $("#list option").attr("selected","selected");
    });
    $("#detColumnSortorder").submit;
  });
});
```

HTML:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <select id="list" name="fieldNames" size="15" multiple="multiple" style="width: 250px;">
        <c:forEach var="field" items="${detFields}">
          <option value="${field.fieldName}">${field.displayName}</option>
        </c:forEach>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="mup">
        <img src="../images/button_up.gif" alt="Hold to move up faster."/>
      </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="mdown">
        <img src="../images/button_down.gif" alt="Hold to move down faster."/>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
      <input name="action" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      <input name="action" type="submit" value="Cancel"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I guess the select scroll bar cannot be accessed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this was interesting.  It looks like there are some bugs with how Chrome/WebKit handle option movement in a select.  I'm not entirely sure what the current behavior is.  Sometimes it moves and sometimes it doesn't.

So, I thought, easy... I'll just code a quick workaround.  Turns out, it's not so easy.  WebKit doesn't provide javascript access to some information, such as option height, etc.

So, after quite a few workarounds I have a hack that seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/7NEqk/

Take it for what it is worth.  Basically, the code tracks selected items within the visible window of the select box.  If the top goes above the visible window, move up, etc.

A couple of notes:

1. You need to iterate through your selected options in reverse when you are moving down `.get().reverse()`, otherwise, if you have adjacent selected items, you will simply have them swap positions, instead of moving down.  (`1` moves below `2`, then `2` moves below `1`).
2. If the browser does not return a height for the option element, I assume a height of `17`.  This is my best guess, but you could tweak it.  Also, this means your options can't be different heights.  I don't think that is possible in WebKit anyway.
3. Before I move the selected item, I check if the item it is swapping with is selected.  If it is, I don't do the swap.  This prevents the selections from swapping around when we get to the bottom or top of the select, where there is nothing to swap with.  It's similar to what I said in note #1, but a slightly different situation.
4. I make the assumption that the selections all fit within the selection frame.  It still works if they aren't, but it could have been handled differently depending on what you wanted.
5. I put `return false;` in the `mousedown` handler.  This is the same as `event.preventDefault()`, etc.  It keeps the button from stealing focus from the select, which in Chrome, makes the selected options turn gray, instead of their normal blue.

Of course, after saying all of this, there is probably a better way of managing this select system in the first place...  But, I took it as a challenge to make it work the way I thought it should.

P.S. Who knows about IE...  I didn't check it, and I am afraid to.

Comment: Man....I thought nobody would be able to help me with this. Im about to dive in and take a look at what you got...be right back

Comment: Well I copied your JS code fromthe fiddle and ran it in IE.  It behaves just like my original code.  In firefox the scroll bar does move when I sort the options.  In chrome it does not.  Weird thing is it seems to submit the form on its own in both firefox and Chrome without me pressing the submit button

Comment: Hmm.  Works great in Chrome for me.  The submit issue is probably coming from some other piece of code.  As for IE, I did some experiments and it is completely screwed up.  IE returns garbage values for the select scroll position and doesn't react correctly to setting the scroll position.  So, basically, I can't figure out a way to make it work in IE.  Have you tried my fiddle in Chrome?  Did the fiddle work?

Comment: The fiddle worked fine in IE, which is why I was surprised...when i took my original code and swapped it in your fiddle it behaved as expected....scroll bar wont react, etc..  When I ran your fiddle it worked.  I took the exact JS you used...compiled code...juts does what my original JS was doing

Comment: Thanks for the help either way